# Material icons font not rendering for some customers

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, webfonts

## Problem

I'm running into an odd, not really reproducible, issue with [Google Material icons](https://design.google.com/icons/). However, a small portion of users are having issues with the font not rendering, I assume the problem is the font resource is not being loaded at all. I've confirmed the issue exists and is wide spread across all OSes, browsers and devices. I used a render test for this confirmation:

```
export default function () {
  let promise = new $.Deferred();
  // Font we know everyone has, in our case it just needs to be variable width
  let fallbackFontFamily = 'sans-serif';
  // The font we're testing
  let fontFamily = 'Material Icons';
  // Add a mix of characters to the DOM so we can measure them. The character
  // choice here is mostly trial and error, trying to differentiate widths
  // between the two fonts
  let $tester = $('<span>@|iLnQW&#xE838;</span>')
      .css('position', 'absolute')
      .css('visibility', 'hidden')
      .css('fontSize', '300px');

  $('body').append($tester);

  function test(repeat) {
    if (repeat == null) {
      repeat = 0;
    }
    // measure the element as if the font has not loaded
    let fallbackWidth = $tester.css('fontFamily', fallbackFontFamily).outerWidth();
    // measure the element as if the font *has* loaded
    let actualWidth = $tester.css('fontFamily', `${fontFamily}, ${fallbackFontFamily}`).outerWidth();

    // if the font has successfully loaded, the widths should not be the same!
    if (fallbackWidth !== actualWidth) {
      promise.resolve();
    } else if (repeat === 0) {
      promise.reject(new Error(`font, ${fontFamily}, failed to load`));
    } else {
      // repeat until finished
      setTimeout(() => test(--repeat), 100);
    }
  }

  // of course, we clean up after ourselves
  promise.always(() => $tester.remove());

  test(10); // repeat 10x
  return promise;
}
```

This is reporting each error back to us, and it appears that roughly 3% of all traffic is affected. I still haven't reproduced the issue myself, except for intentionally messing with the network. A simple refresh tends to fix the problem, further leading me to believe it's a resource loading problem, but on the browser, or OS's part, not the network.

## Debugging

With the issue now being measured I've started to take a few steps to address the issue, none of this has produced any results, but is probably useful to know:

- Originally, the Google hosted stylesheet and fonts were being used, [as instructed here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-1-using-via-google-web-fonts).
- I switched to a self hosted stylesheet, to eliminate that network request. I simply copied and pasted it from the original.
- Then I began self hosting the fonts and updated `@font-face` accordingly. I left the Google hosted versions as a fallback, simply for redundancy.
- Finally I removed the local version of the font from `@font-face` in case customers have some oddly broken version of the font (at this point I'm just trying anything, no clue if this would actually *do* anything)

The final state of the stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v17/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5UEw0lE80llgEseQY3FEmqw.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v17/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5RV6cRhDpPC5P4GCEJpqGoc.woff) format('woff'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v17/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5StnKWgpfO2iSkLzTz-AABg.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

I have confirmed that the self hosted fonts do work correctly in the normal case. I believe this testing has eliminated *most* of the potential for error on my end. Now I just have no idea what is happening. Are some browsers just not loading the font at all? Are there any other ways that I should be measuring or monitoring these kinds of issues? And, most importantly, how can I fix this!?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that could be attributed to a simple glitch in network connectivity. Browsers getting stuck in FOUT, or even worse, FOIT, is a real problem that web developers have to account for.

For better monitoring I'd suggest using [Font Face Observer](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) to load the fonts in your production environment (a good idea anyway), and do some debugging/logging when the fonts fail to load.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the Font Face Observer suggestion. I through that in as fast as I could. It like it's implementation far more than mine. I still have not been able to get to the bottom of the problem and have since switched to SVG icons. Very odd issue. There are roughly 4 other web fonts being loaded with out any issues what so ever.

Comment: I've been seeing recent issues loading material fonts for my angular application from Google on iPhone - which makes it very hard to debug!